# Is there any way of multiplying a column of pandas with every other column and get a list of products?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

Is there any way of multiplying a column of pandas with every other column and get a list of sum of products?
I'll try to brief my problem Let;s assume my data set is

```
Label  X   Y1  Y2
=================
abc    4   0   1
xyz    0   1   0
...    2   3   2
...    3   2   4
...    4   4   3
...    2   1   0
```

I would require a list list_sum

```
list_sum = [sum(X*Y1), sum(X*Y2)]
```

Every element in Column `X` is multiplied with corresponding element in column `Y1` and all the numbers are added, same is done with Y1.
in this case list_sum should be

```
list_sum = [30, 32]
```

But my requirement is for a dataframe containing n columns, without iterating using a for loop, as that could really cost my computation time.
If i am missing anything or info insufficient I'll be sure to update on Notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generic way to do it:

```
# list of columns to be multiplied by X
columns = list(set(df.columns).difference("X"))
print(columns)

sum_list = [sum(df["X"]*df[i]) for i in columns]
print(sum_list)
```

**Edit**

```
columns = list(set(df.columns).difference("X"))

df_ = df[columns].multiply(df["X"], axis="index")

print(df_.sum().tolist())
```

Comment: sum_list = [sum(df["X"]*df[i]) for i in columns]  
I'd want to avoid this for.

Comment: @VjsPranav any reason to avoid this approach? Coz here you are not iterating over dataframe, you are iterating over columns

Comment: It's a part of project i am doing.   
2 Reasons    
1) The number of columns can be really large. (avoiding iterating through columns was what i actually intended to mean)
2) We are not allowed to use for loops, and instead try to do it with seeing the data as cvectors.

Comment: What could be done to avoid a loop,(Let's say if i'm fine with no list)?

Comment: Checked. It still covers the case of only 2 Columns whereas there are n

Comment: That was covered in first part of answer.. check now

Comment: That did the trick although i'd have to do this for removing the column.  ((...).difference('X') didn't work.)
`columns = list(set(df.columns))
columns.remove('X')`